# Using a bounding-box filter on a Overpass union

Tags: overpass-api

I'm trying to filter the result of an Overpass union using a bounding box.

This [works](http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/Apf):

```
(
  rel["natural"="wood"]({{bbox}});
  rel["landuse"="forest"]({{bbox}});
);
(._;>;);
out;
```

But it requires me to repeat the bounding box twice (or even more often when there are additional queries in the union). Therefore, I'd like to apply the filter after the union, which [doesn't seem to work](http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/Apg):

```
(
  rel["natural"="wood"];
  rel["landuse"="forest"];
)({{bbox}});
(._;>;);
out;
```

The error message I get is

```
Error: line 4: parse error: ';' expected - '(' found.
```

Comment: Please refer to the documentation, keyword is "Global Bounding Box". What do you mean by "Turbopass union"??? overpass turbo is the name of the web frontend, Overpass API is the database backend serving the data, and union is a language construct provided by Overpass API.

Comment: @mmd I've fixed the "Turbopass union" typo, thanks for pointing it out! If I understand it correctly, using a [Global Bounding Box](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/Overpass_QL#Global_bounding_box_.28bbox.29) would set the bounding box for all my queries -- this means I couldn't have two separate unions with different bounding boxes.

Comment: Yes, that's correct, a global bounding box setting applies to all statements, like in your example. From your question, it's not really obvious that you want to use different bounding boxes for different statements. The only thing you could do is to add additional bounding boxes to single statements to further restrict your global bounding box.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, @mmd! If you post that as an answer I'd be happy to accept it.